# Overrule borders from tables in css

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to remove the border above the 111 column but it isn't working for some reason. Can anyone explain how I can overrule the border-style?

```css
.myBorder {
  border-top-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="myBorder">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top-style: none !important;">111</td>
    <td>222</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>333</td>
    <td>444</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see I tried it with `!important` but it isn't working.

Comment: Your border is set on the table, not the table cell, which is why your inline CSS isn't making a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use border-collapse on the table and then draw a white top-border on the cell

```css
.myBorder {
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table class="myBorder">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top-style:solid; border-color:white;">111</td>
    <td>222</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>333</td>
    <td>444</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```